# ruby connect to MS SQL no rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have been trying to connect to a local `MS SQLExpress` database and I am having no luck.  I was trying to use DBI and DBD-ODBC gems and keep getting the

> Unable to load driver 'ODBC'underlying error: uninitialized constant `DBI::DBD::ODBC`).

From reading the threads on stackoverflow it appears that these gems are not used any longer.

I am now trying to use tinytds.  I am NOT using rails at this time so I do not have a database.yml file to modify.

My question is two-fold do I need to install rails to access a local `MS SQLExpress server` on a Windows 7 machine and is `tinytds` the correct gem to use?

SOLUTION:

For me I had to turn off 'Windows Authentication Mode', I used SQL Management Studio.
The connection string and setup is as follows in IRB.

```
require 'tiny_tds'
client = TinyTds::client.new(:username => 'test', :password => 'test', :dataserver => 'computername\SQLEXPRESS', :database => 'database1')
client.active? (returns true now)
```

Comment: `tinytds` is what you want to use follow the instructions at https://github.com/rails-sqlserver/tiny_tds its pretty straightforward

Comment: see below.  I was able to get it working, I believe.

Comment: you can simply post your solution as an answer, so others can learn from it, and accept it as an answer

Answer (score 0):

Try reading the TinyTDS documentation. Taken [directly from the README](https://github.com/rails-sqlserver/tiny_tds#tinytdsclient-usage):

````
Connect to a database.

client = TinyTds::Client.new(:username => 'sa', :password => 'secret', :host => 'mydb.host.net```
````

It looks like you do not need rails to use TinyTDS. Whether or not this is 'correct' is up to what your goals/needs are. If you need to connect to a MSSql database with Ruby, then this looks to be a good route.

Comment: it is not like it "looks like" I have used it with pure ruby apps in the past

Comment: I am using this page as a guide, my confusion is the page is labled "rails-sqlserver".  I will continue following this guide and modify my client.rb file and see how it goes.

Comment: turns out my sql server was set to Microsoft authentication, I changed it to login with name and password and my client connects and is now active.  Thanks for the help.